# Extjs Grid Paging bar problem

Tags: extjs

I am getting paging issue when i delete the final record from last page, how can i resolve the paging issue, pls view the screen shot which i have attached.

[image]

In Store save event i will reload the store for update the grid for remote sort.

like this

```
var fGridStore = new Ext.data.Store({       
    proxy:ApGrpFGrdProxy,                       
    autoLoad :false,
    autoSave:false,
    idProperty:'airBasicIndex',
    baseParams:{start:0, limit:25}, 
    reader:firstGridreader,
    writer: fssuperGrdWriter,
    listeners:{

                save  :function ( St,  records, options ){
                    St.reload();                        
                    }
        },
    remoteSort:true
});
```

In Grid..

```
bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar({
                    pageSize: 25,
                    store: fGridStore,
                    displayInfo: true,                      
                    emptyMsg: "No records to display"
                }),
```

**if you view my screen shot.. 5 of 4 will be the page when i delete the final record in last page ..how can i move to the previous page when i delete the final record in the last page.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the moveLast() method on the toolbar to for the navigation to go to the last page?

[API Docs for PagingToolbar.moveLast()](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/PagingToolbar.html#method-Ext.PagingToolbar-moveLast)

Comment: hi "It Grunt" thnk for ur reply,  how will we identify it is the last record in the last page ..then only i think we can use this method..else it will always moves to the last page for all delete event.....is it right or it will work out?

Comment: This should work since you want to move to the page that contains the last event.  As suggested in the previous answer, you should use the Ext.data.Store.getTotalCount() to see what the total number of records in the store is before going to the last page on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best practice in this case is returning Total Row Count with each request.
You shoud reload your store after delete action.
Then you can configure your reader to use Total Row Count.
Then problem will disapear automatically.
See Ext.data.JsonReader API Doc.

```
var myReader = new
Ext.data.JsonReader({
// metadata configuration options:
 idProperty: 'id'
 root: 'rows',
 totalProperty: 'results',
 Ext.data.DataReader.messageProperty:
 "msg"  // The element within the
 response that provides a user-feedback
 message (optional)

     // the fields config option will internally create an Ext.data.Record
     // constructor that provides mapping for reading the record data
 objects
     fields: [
         // map Record's 'firstname' field to data object's key of same
 name
         {name: 'name'},
         // map Record's 'job' field to data object's 'occupation' key
         {name: 'job', mapping: 'occupation'}
     ] });
```

Comment: reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'res',
            id: 'HJid',
            idProperty: 'arOpDefIndex',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message',          
            fields: fields
        }),